# How to call a js function on click of a grid cell?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs-grid

I want a javascript function to be called as I click on a cell in grid .I want code for the same using extjs 3.4. How can I achieve it? can anyone help me out in it?

Comment: Have you checked out cell click event listener? Info in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-cellclick)

Answer (score 0):

Set the selection model to `CellSelectionModel` and call your function on cell select:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    // ..
    sm: new Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel({  
        listeners: {
            cellselect: function(sm, row, col) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('click','got a click!');
            }
        }
    })
})
```